# Why is this PDF rescaling Automator script misfires?

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, automator, pdf

I am using an Automator to convert folders of A4-sized PDFs to other formats.
It uses PDF GhostScript though I have not personally written the code, somebody on discussions.apple.com helped me at the time.
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gsnnm4h6l7g05cv/AADmooCoJKiIb9KHtD4JgJrOa?dl=0) is the full Automator which should output PDFs that are sized at 638 x 850 pt.
For reasons beyond my understanding, all PDFs come out at 601 x 850 pt.
No error is thrown by the Automator.

Can someone help me with this?
I am also pasting the script directly below here.

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/Desktop
EXT="_iPad.pdf"
OUTFOLDER="$1"
shift 1

function pdf_rescale () {
    /usr/local/bin/pdfscale.sh -r 'custom pt 638 850' -s 1.0 "${1}" "${2}"
    return
}

# loop through all input files, or folders and transform A4 PDF to 225x300 PDF scaled to 100 percent
for f in "$@"
do
    # is it a directory?
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        # nullglob prevents expansion of "*.pdf" to variable x if no match
        shopt -s nullglob
        for x in "${f}"/*.pdf
        do
            shopt -s extglob
            pdf_rescale "${x}" "${OUTFOLDER}/${x//+(*\/|.*)}${EXT}"
            shopt -u extglob
        done
        shopt -u nullglob
    # is it a non-zero, regular file?
    elif [ -s "$f" ]; then
        shopt -s extglob
        pdf_rescale "${f}" "${OUTFOLDER}/${f//+(*\/|.*)}${EXT}"
        shopt -u extglob
    fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: I have GhostScript installed, but I don't have a script `/usr/local/bin/pdfscale.sh`. So the contents of that script might be relevant to the problem.

Comment: I have three copies of this Automator, they differ only in the numbers of point the converted output size is. 2/3 work perfectly, this one doesn’t...